# Cross account GCS access using Spark on Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to ingest data in GCS of account A to BigQuery of account B using Spark running on Dataproc in account B.

I have tried to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to service account key file which allows access to necessary bucket in account A. But if I start `spark-shell` I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error accessing Bucket dataproc-40222d04-2c40-42f9-a5de-413a123f949d-asia-south1
```

As per my understanding, setting the environment variable is switching the access from account B to account A.

Is there a way to have both the accesses within Spark i.e., default access to account B and additional access to account A?

Update: I tried running `spark-shell` with configuration as per [Igor's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453939/5216598), but the error prevails. Here's the command I tried and the stack trace.

```
$ spark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/home/shasank/watchful-origin-299914-fa29998bad08.json --jars gs://hadoop-lib/bigquery/bigquery-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error accessing Bucket dataproc-40999d04-2b99-99f9-a5de-999ad23f949d-asia-south1
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getBucket(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1895)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getItemInfo(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1846)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfoInternal(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1125)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1116)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.exists(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:440)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configureBuckets(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1738)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.configureBuckets(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:76)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1659)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:683)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:646)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3242)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:121)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3291)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:470)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.org$apache$spark$deploy$DependencyUtils$$resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:165)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$doPrepareSubmitEnvironment$3.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$doPrepareSubmitEnvironment$3.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:403)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doPrepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:171)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by:
com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException:
  403 Forbidden {
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "message" : "ingestor@watchful-origin-299914.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to dataproc-40999d04-2b99-99f9-a5de-999ad23f949d-asia-south1.",
      "reason" : "forbidden" } ],
    "message" : "ingestor@watchful-origin-299914.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to  dataproc-40999d04-2b99-99f9-a5de-999ad23f949d-asia-south1." }
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:401)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1097)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:499)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getBucket(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1889)
  ... 32 more
```

Comment: Did you authorize your service account to access to your bucket? Can you be precise when you speak about "account"? Do you soak about project or service account?

Comment: Yes the service account is authorized to access the bucket. By "account" I mean "GCP account". More specifically account A is my customer's GCP account and account B is my GCP account where I am building a data lake.

Comment: Which role? Object reader or bucket admin?

Comment: Storage Object Viewer role.

Comment: Hmm, try storage admin. My guess is the following: Sometime, libraries perform a bucket.list API call before getting the object, don't know why, and it's different according with the language. If you want, you can create a custom role only with bucket.list and bucket.get permission for reducing privileges

Comment: I found an issue, seems to be related https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/135

Comment: How about your GCE VMs' scopes? Sometimes roles aren't enough to interact with some components. Make sure that the Storage and BigQuery scopes are enabled in your GCE VMs.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my answer with instructions on how to disable this bucket check.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you need to re-configure GCS and BQ connectors to use different service accounts for authentication, by default both of them are using GCE VM service account.

To do so, please, refer to the [Method 2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md#method-2) in the GCS connector configuration manual.

The same configuration applies to Hadoop BQ connector, but  you need to replace `fs.gs.` prefix in the properties names with `bq.mapred.` prefix:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/path/to/local/gcs/key/file.json
spark.hadoop.bq.mapred.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/path/to/local/bq/key/file.json
```

**Update:**

To disable Dataproc staging bucket check during GCS connector initialization, you need to use latest GCS connector version (1.9.17 at the moment) and set GCS connector system bucket property to empty string:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.system.bucket=
```

Note, that this system bucket functionality is removed in upcoming GCS connector 2.0, so this will be not an issue going forward.

Comment: I tried this, but when I use GCS key file for account A, DataProc looses access to its own GCS (which I believe it uses to store temp file). So it results in the same error which I originally posted.
I don't think it will allow me to specify 2 keys files in spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile, I will try that though.

Comment: One service account with permissions in 2 projects is what you need.

Comment: It is not 2 projects within a single GCP account. It is 2 different GCP account altogether.
Is there a way to create such service account?

Comment: You can try to specify 2nd account during job submission not cluster creation. Also you [can set a different service account for the Dataproc cluster](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts) too.

Comment: Also, setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` could have an unintended  consequences because it  applies not only to GCS and BQ connectors, but to the all Google API client libraries.

Comment: I am creating the cluster without any Service Account, so it is using the default and thus it has access to the Dataproc staging bucket. But when I start spark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=/path/to/accountA/serviceAccount.json, it completely forgets about the default service account and thus complains of not having access to the staging bucket.

Comment: May you post a full stack trace when it complains about access to staging bucket?

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak The updated answer helps to start the `spark-shell` by bypassing the initial bucket check. But I come to the same problem while writing to BigQuery, since IndirectBigQueryOutputFormat requires a temporary write location on GCS. And for me this location has to be in account B (which is where destination BigQuery dataset is). So I think I would still require a way to have simultaneous access to GCS bucket on 2 different GCP account.

Comment: In this case you need to create a single service account that has access to both GCS and BQ that you want, because what are you trying to do is not supported at the moment